# nginx dynamic redirection of url

Tags: nginx, websocket

I dynamically open and close websockets on the server's end with port in range from 5700 to 5800.
Web clients have access to port 80 on which a web server runs (nginx).
I need my clients to access those websockets through port 80, I am thinking about generaing a url for each accesssible websocket (such as www.my-site/websocket/5701) and proxyfying it through nginx (to the websocket on port 5701).

Is there a way I can dynamically tell nginx to redirect traffic from the generated url to the websocket?

Would my solution work if traffic was encrypted from the client to the web server port 80, but not from nginx to the websocket?

EDIT : 
I have a working solution but I would like to make it more generic (from ports 5700 to 5750 in one block)

```
location /websocket/5700 {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5700;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically! Can you tell me little more in depth.

Comment: I mean that the websockets can open or close at any time. While writing my question I realized that that fact did not mattered much, the proxy can be left opened

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by using:

```
location ~ /websocket/(.*)$ {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$1;
}
```